# Why am I getting this error Notice: Undefined index: host

Tags: php

my sample code is here

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
function get_all_links($url){
    global $host;
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load(file_get_contents($url));

    foreach($html->find('a') as $a){
        $host1 = parse_url($a->href);
        $host = parse_url($url);
            if($host1['host'] == $host['host']){
                    $data[] = $a->href;
            }
    }
    return $data;

}
$links = get_all_links("http://www.example.com/");

foreach($links as $link){
   echo $link."<br />";
}
```

When I try this code, I got this error: Notice: Undefined index: host in... What's wrong in my code? Please suggest me some helping code, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: echo '<pre>', print_r($host), '</pre>'; - what does that give you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check if the arrays contain entries for `'host'` using [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) before assuming they exist:

```
if (isset($host1['host']) && isset($host['host']) 
        && $host1['host'] == $host['host']) {
```

Or you can [use `@` to suppress warnings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) from the check.

```
if (@$host1['host'] == @$host['host']) {
```

However, you'll need to double-check that the latter works as you desire when both are missing.

**Update:** As the others pointed out there is also [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php). It will handle `null` array values whereas `isset` returns `false` for `null` values.

Comment: I would definitely favour `isset()` over error suppression, especially for checking indices. Suppressions are a bad habit.

Answer (score 2):

As others have answered, both [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [`array_key_exists()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) will work here. `isset()` is nice, because it can actually take multiple arguments:

```
if (isset($array[0], $array[1], $array[2]))
{
    // ...
}

// same as

if (isset($array[0]) && isset($array[1]) && isset($array[2]))
{
    // ...
}
```

Returning `true` only if all arguments are set.

Comment: I always forget about `isset` taking multiple arguments but cannot recall a recent need for it. It also handles multiple array levels in one call such as `isset($array1['foo']['bar'])`.

Answer (score 0):

you can find out if an array has an index called "host" using `array_key_exists`

```
if (array_key_exists($host, "host") && array_key_exists($host1, "host") && ...)
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

For me, the Protocol was missing from WordPress database for `siteurl` and `home`

Used `MySQL` to change these in `wp_options` from `Domain_Name` to `https://DOMAIN_ NAME`.

Hope this helps took me hours to figure it out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).