# Wordpress on Xamp server — Undefined index: host

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've recently setup Wordpress locally using XAMP on windows 7. I've created an SQL database for my install and setup some config files to handle the live server and local for use when I start using git.

I have a **wp-local-config.php**:

```
<?php 
// Local server settings

// Local Database
define('DB_NAME', '<mysiteuser>');
define('DB_USER', '<mydbuser>');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '<db password>');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

// Overwrites the database to save keep edeting the DB
define('WP_HOME','/client.dev');
define('WP_SITEURL','/client.dev');

// Turn on debug for local environment
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

And my **wp-config.php**

```
<?php

// Use these settings on the local server
if ( file_exists( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-local-config.php' ) ) {
  include( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-local-config.php' );

// Otherwise use the below settings (on live server)
} else {

  // Live Server Database Settings
  define( 'DB_NAME',     '<live db name>');
  define( 'DB_USER',     '<live db user>');
  define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '<live db pw>' );
  define( 'DB_HOST',     'localhost'  );

  // Overwrites the database to save keep edeting the DB
  define('WP_HOME','http://<client url>');
  define('WP_SITEURL','http://<client url>');

  // Turn Debug off on live server
  define('WP_DEBUG', false);
}
```

However when I login to my wordpress install I get lots of debug errors such as:

(At the top of the screen)

```
Notice: Undefined index: host in C:\xampp\htdocs\client.dev\wp-includes\theme.php on line 1820
Notice: Undefined index: host in C:\xampp\htdocs\client.dev\wp-includes\theme.php on line 1820
Notice: Undefined index: host in C:\xampp\htdocs\client.dev\wp-includes\theme.php on line 1876
Notice: Undefined index: host in C:\xampp\htdocs\client.dev\wp-includes\theme.php on line 1876
```

In the wordpress new:

```
Notice: Undefined index: host in C:\xampp\htdocs\client.dev\wp-includes\http.php on line 470
Notice: Undefined index: host in C:\xampp\htdocs\client.dev\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 129
```

Can anyone help me find out why this is happening?

Comment: On a general note with XAMPP, which i use and like, change all the default passwords. If you have it 'internet facing' then you **must** do this. As you will be found by all and sundry. It is not amusing. ;-/ Especially, change DAV. ;-/ I use windows xp, oi - stop laffin' :-)

Comment: Did you try an absolute URL for WP_HOME/WP_SITEURL in your wp-local-config.php?

Comment: check similar issue with solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9882810/1140227

Comment: have you configured virtual host for that folder under htdocs\client.dev ? or at least provide me which url you are accessing to install

Answer (score 5):

@Mat-visual:

As user RDrazard pointed out: in your wp-local-config.php, change these two lines:

```
define('WP_HOME','/client.dev');
define('WP_SITEURL','/client.dev');
```

To look like this:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/client.dev');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/client.dev');
```

I tested this with my own local installation of WordPress and it cleared up the errors you were getting.  Hope you find this helpful!

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend something similar, but to avoid hard coding anything for your site I do:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_SITEURL','http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the url to absolute path as "`http://localhost/client.dev`".

In case the problem persists, change the localhost to 127.0.0.1 resulting in the path address like this

`http://127.0.0.1/client.dev`

and do the required changes in all urls.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is about some array doesn't have index 'host' in file theme.php, ex:

```
$array['host']
```

And it isn't error, just notice, you can hide the notice using:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

If you don't mind, please add more part of theme.php, and I can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

This should sort it...

define('WP_HOME','http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_SITEURL','http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);